# ServiceStack doesn't auto-wire and register AppSettings

Tags: c#, servicestack, ioc-container

ServiceStack (4.0.62) doesn't register and auto-wire AppSettings property. I even don't know how to debug this situation, maybe somebody can explain it.

So, I have ServiceStack-based self-hosted console windows application (default IoC Funq is used):

```
    public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("SomeServer", typeof (SomeService).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {
                DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json,
                DebugMode = true,
            });

            AppSettings = new DictionarySettings(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Key1", "Value1" },
                { "Key2", "Value2" },
            });

            // Enable plugins
            Plugins.Add(...);
        }
    }
```

SomeService's AppSettings property isn't initialized at all:

```
    public class SomeService : Service
    {
        public IAppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

        public SomeResponse Get(SomeRequest request)
        {
            // Exception: AppSettings == null
            var someValue = AppSettings.Get<string>("Key1");

            // ...
        }
    }
```

How can is possible? What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack does [register the IAppSettings in Funq](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/5fb82e82e22f10e73856802568920734264c531b/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStackHost.cs#L522-L523) by default.

I've also verified this using your example in a new Self-Host Console App:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("SomeServer", typeof(SomeService).Assembly) {}
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        SetConfig(new HostConfig {
            DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json,
            DebugMode = true,
        });

        AppSettings = new DictionarySettings(new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "Key1", "Value1" },
            { "Key2", "Value2" },
        });
    }
}

[Route("/appsettings/{Key}")]
public class SomeRequest
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class SomeResponse
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class SomeService : Service
{
    public IAppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

    public SomeResponse Get(SomeRequest request)
    {
        return new SomeResponse { Value = AppSettings.Get<string>(request.Key) };
    }
}
```

That starts with:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new AppHost().Init().Start("http://*:8088/");
        "ServiceStack Self Host with Razor listening at http://127.0.0.1:8088".Print();
        Process.Start("http://127.0.0.1:8088/");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Which is working as expected, i.e:

- http://127.0.0.1:8088/appsettings/Key1.json => `{"Value":"Value1"}`

Check [?debug=requestinfo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#request-info) to see if you have any `StartUpErrors` which could have impeded the initialization of the AppHost.

Comment: thank you for support. I read SS documentation and was sure that it must do register IAppSettings by default. I tried your sample - everything works great. But in my real project registration doesn't work at all. Everything except registration. It's unbelievable, `StartUpErrors` is empty, see [full log](http://pastebin.com/yMs18HQ8). I was wrong about ServiceStack version, it was 4.0.56, now it's 4.0.62 but nothing changed. In my case AppHost starts with "http://+:8088/", other options are same.

Comment: @AlexNewman Can't tell what the issue is from here. Can you publish a stand-alone repro that I can run locally to see the issue, ideally in a new Github repo or .zip share on Google Docs, Dropbox, etc.

Comment: it was my fault, excuse me, it was a really bad idea to use Service's constructor to implement some AppSettings-actions. The question is closed, thank you so much.